# How to force ssl and www for all subdomains and domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl, subdomain

I was searching a lot on this topic, but non of the threads I found worked for me. I want to have a proper permanent rewrite rule for the following:

- http(s)://anysubdomain.domain.tld(/) -> https://www.domain.tld
- http(s)://domain.tld(/) -> https://www.domain.tld
- http(s)://anysubdomain.domain.tld/foo/bar(/) -> https://www.domain.tld/foo/bar
- http(s)://domain.tld/foo/bar(/) -> https://www.domain.tld/foo/bar

Anything I tried up to now doesn't capture all subdomains or causes a redirect loop or redirects more than once...

Currently I'm running this, just to have at least www and https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (?!^www\.)^(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should be working even if i would not have written it that way. About redirect loop, what redirects do you get (you can check http headers) ?

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have other rules also?

Comment: Hi! In fact it works when I open the URL in Windows/linux browsers, but is doesn't work on android firefox or opera.

Comment: You may test it for http://domaineck.de works on windows, not on android firefox. Wheird...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache rewrite from subdomain to www but keep all permalinks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895637/apache-rewrite-from-subdomain-to-www-but-keep-all-permalinks)

Comment: Mmh... I cannot find an error. Jww, What exactly you mean?

Comment: Hi All! I have checked all the redirects using http://www.redirect-checker.org/. The conclusion is, that all the redirects are working as they should. So no problem with htaccess; I think. But, the redirects are not working on all my android devices (except chrome browser). Do you think this is a htaccess problem or related to the  android firefox and opera. I googled, found similar problems, but no solution...